# Intelij Java persistence imports work except for namedquery

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm working on a local project where i'm using JPA, so far my configuration worked but i'm encountering the following error while importing the javax.persistence named query.

[image]

I have no idea why this one import is giving an error, besides the code also works when i run the project.

This is my module-info file, which seems to be working fine too

[image]

and here are my used JARs for JPA

[image]

i'm at a loss as to what is cousing this error, does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: Does it help if you point the cursor at the error in the editor, press Alt + Enter, and apply a suggested fix for your module-info.java?

Comment: then i get the error that the module is trying to read javax.persistence from two different packages 

`java: module project2 reads package javax.persistence from both java.persistence and org.eclipse.persistence.asm`

because it puts `requires org.eclipse.persistence.asm` in my module.info along with `java.persistence`